# Android, How to get single item of a row in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in my activity.
Each row includes three TextViews in this pattern: (**RowId**) (**Name**) (**Phone number**)

I need to get row id when user clicks on a row. I did so many things and search the net, however i didn't find a solution. I have no idea how to get row id from following method:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.i(TAG, "item " + position + " clicked.");

        }
});
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of "onItemClick"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also could use `v.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId)`

Comment: Wow, You are amazing Ixx. After 5 hours searching finally you solved my problem. Thanks again. other ways were useless for me.

Comment: I get NullPointException

Answer (score 0):

to get row element

use `v.findViewById(<id of row element>)`;

you can use get get object data in list ...........

```
<your_adapter>.getItem(position);
```

or

`parent.getItemAtPosition (position);`

both will return the Object....

Comment: Thanks dear Dheeresh. The problem is it is returning null each time. I wrote something like: TextView tv = (TextView) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Log.i(TAG, ">> " + tv.getText());

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `v.getChildAt(0)` if you are sure that the `ListView` item is formed directly by those three `TextView`'s